# Comparing a computer IP address against an IP in a CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, ip

Beating my head against the wall here for something I am sure is super simple. I am trying to compare the ipv4 wifi address of a computer and if it matches an IP in an imported CSV, perform an action.

If I manually enter an IP to compare, it works fine and returns a match.

```
$IP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias wi-fi).IPAddress
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Windows\Temp\List.csv"

foreach ($CPU in $CSV){
if ($CPU.IP -like "10.101*"){write-host "match found"}
}
```

If I try and compare against data in a CSV, it doesn't match.

```
$IP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias wi-fi).IPAddress
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Windows\Temp\List.csv"

foreach ($CPU in $CSV){
if ($CPU.IP -like $IP){write-host "match found"}
}
```

The contents of the CSV is as follows

| SITE | IP |
| --- | --- |
| Site01 | 10.101 |
| Site02 | 10.102 |

I have tried every variation of MATCH, LIKE, CONTAINS etc...
I have tried using [STRING] at the beginning of Get-NetIPAddress....

It seems to be that when I use -like $IP it really wants -like $IP* with a wildcard but I can't figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Consider whether you might want to use `-match` and a regexp instead of using `-like`. Note that your CSV does _not_ contain IP addresses; the values aren't even proper CIDR subnet masks.

Comment: I know it doesn't contain IP addresses. All I care about is if a computer has an IP address of 10.101.xx.xx that it matches what's in the CSV so it can do a site-specific action. MATCH doesn't seem to work either. Basically, if the IP address contains .101. then do SITE01 action. If it contains .102. then do SITE02 action.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with the following...

```
$IP -like ($CPU.IP + "*")
```

Didn't really know you could append a wildcard like that. Credit to purplemonkeymad on Reddit for the tip!

Comment: Nice, though it's better to use `+ ".*"`, so that, e.g. `10.10` in the CSV doesn't accidentally match both `10.10.x.x` and `10.102.x.x`.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the -like operator in PowerShell expects a wildcard (*) to be used in the pattern you're comparing to.

So if you want to find an IP address that starts with the value of $IP, you need to append a * to it, which can be done using string concatenation:

```
$IP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias wi-fi).IPAddress
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Windows\Temp\List.csv"

foreach ($CPU in $CSV){
    if ($CPU.IP -like "$IP*"){write-host "match found"}
}
```

This should now match if $CPU.IP starts with the same string as $IP.

But be aware that -like is case-insensitive. If you want a case-sensitive match, use -clike.

If this still doesn't work, please ensure that $IP does indeed contain the value you expect it to contain.

If you want to compare if $CPU.IP contains $IP anywhere (not just at the beginning), you should use * on both sides of $IP:

```
$IP = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias wi-fi).IPAddress
$CSV = Import-Csv "C:\Windows\Temp\List.csv"

foreach ($CPU in $CSV){
    if ($CPU.IP -like "*$IP*"){write-host "match found"}
}
```

This will match if $CPU.IP contains the string $IP anywhere in it.

Comment: `$IP` is a _full_ IP address, whereas it is `$CPU.IP` that is the fragment. You're applying the wildcard (`*`) in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

At first you isolate the first to numbers of the IPv4-Address.  In my case it is "192.168"

```
$IPMatchKey = (Get-NetIPAddress -AddressFamily IPv4 -InterfaceAlias "wi-fi").IPAddress -replace "\.\d+\.\d+$"
```

As next you will find the Site by $IPMatchKey in CSV file.  In my case it returns "HomeSite"

```
(Import-Csv -Path "<AnyPath>\IPSites.csv" -Delimiter ";" | Where-Object { $PSItem.IP -like $IPMatchKey }).Site
```

The CSV file is this ...

```
SITE;IP
Site01;10.101
Site02;10.102
HomeSite;192.168
```

That's it.